# I am making a Menu driven program in which i have to create, delete and insert an array

Tags: arrays, c

I am making a Menu driven program in which I have to create, delete and insert an array but when I am calling the delete or insert function because of that my code is not running please help. please tell me how to call the function so the code can run. if I remove of comment the calling of indDelete and IndInsert my code is running perfectly but as I uncomment them the code does not run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
//printing the array
void display(int arr[], int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){          
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf(" /n");
}

//insertion function
int indInsert(int arr[], int capacity, int size, int element, int index){

    if(size>=capacity){                 
        return -1;
    }
    for(int i = size-1; i >= index; i--){              
        arr[i+1] = arr[i];
    }
    arr[index] = element;
    return 1;
}

//deletion function
int indDelete(int arr[], int capacity, int size, int index){
    if(index > capacity || index < 0){
          return -1;
    }
    for(int i = index; i < size-1; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    }
    return 1;
}

//driver code 
int main(){
    int capacity, arr[capacity], size;
    printf("Enter the capacity of an array \n");
    scanf("%d", &capacity);
    printf("Enter the number of elements you want to enter \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("Enter the elements:- \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    bool check = false;
    int exit = 0, element = 0, index = 0;;
    while(check == false){
        printf("If you want to insert an element press 1 \n");
        printf("If you want to delete an element press 2 \n");
        printf("If you want to exit press 3 \n");
        scanf("%d", &exit);

        switch(exit){
        case 1:
            printf("Enter the element:- \n");
            scanf("%d", &element);
            printf("Enter the index:- \n");
            scanf("%d", &index);

            printf("The present Array \n");
            display(arr, size);
            printf("The insterted array \n");
            indInsert(arr,capacity,size,element,index);
            size +=1;
            display(arr, size);
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Enter the index:- \n");
            scanf("%d", &index);

            printf("The present Array \n");
            display(arr, size);
            printf("The insterted array \n");
            indDelete(arr,capacity,size,index);
            size -= 1;
            display(arr, size);
            break;
            
        case 3:
            printf("Thank you for using the program");
            check = 111;
            break;

        default:
            printf("Error: Wrong cmd");
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first line of main you have

```
int capacity, arr[capacity], size;
```

Which means `arr` is an array of unknown size, because `capacity` isn't defined yet. Even if you change `capacity` later, the array size won't change.

If you turn on your compiler warnings you will probably be notified of this, like with `-Wall` for gcc or `/Wall` for msvc.